# iteration progress detection Java

Tags: java

I wanted to check if the iteration I was executing was in its final execution:

```
for(String t: token)
```

How can I achieve this in the following case ? Here token is a `String[]` array

Comment: yes token here is a String.

Comment: `token` should be `String[]`

Comment: You can't. If you need it, use a conventional for loop.

Comment: Why not simply use a for loop and do a if(i+1==token.length){whatever yo want there}

Comment: Just iterate the old-fashioned way, with an integer index, and check when it equals `token.length - 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you

```
  int counter=0;
  for(String t: token){
        counter++;
        if(counter==token.length-1)){

        }

    }
```

But if you need focused on indexes you can use just a `for-loop`

```
   for(int i=0;i<token.length;i++){
       if(i==token.length-1){

        }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
      int counter = 0;
      for(String t: token) {
          counter++;
          if(counter==token.length-1) {
              //final iteration
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

With fast enumeration, you cannot retrieve the iteration's index.

However you can always use a counter that increments within your fast-enumeration loop, and act when its value is equal to the `Collection` or array's size minus 1.

Here's an example.

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
// TODO populate
// outside counter
int counter = 0;
for (String s: test) {
    // TODO something
    // checking counter vs collection size: last element
    if (counter == test.size() - 1) {
        // TODO something
    }
    counter++;
}
```

However, a standard `for` loop would be most recommended instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
    // checking counter vs collection size: last element
    if (i == test.size() - 1) {
        // TODO something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is `Iterable` you can walk the iterator yourself:

```
List<String> token = Arrays.asList("First","Next","Last");
// Old way
for ( String t : token) {
  System.out.println(t);
}
// Using iterator.
for ( Iterator<String> i = token.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
  String s = i.next();
  System.out.println((i.hasNext()?"":"*")+s);
}
```

or you could walk one step behind:

```
// One step behind.
String s = null;
for ( String t : token) {
  if ( s != null ) {
    System.out.println(s);
  }
  s = t;
}
if ( s != null ) {
  System.out.println("*"+s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use while?

```
int i = 0;
while(i < token.length)
{
    //check for last element
     if(i==token.length-1){

      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just providing another way to do this using equals.

```
for(String t: token) {
  if(t.equals(token[token.length-1])) {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```